# Aggreagte Mongo Db query to Spring MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I have same ID testCaseId 'tc1' mapped with 2 requirementId 'req1' and 'req10'. This below query gives the exact match for project--proj001,req--req10 and tc--tc1. I got the solution but unable to convert this query into Spring Mongo.

```
db.req_tc.aggregate([  
    { $match: {'project': 'proj001'}},  
    { $project: {  
        list: {$filter: {  
            input: '$reqtclst',  
            as: 'item',  
            cond: {  
                 $and: [  
                {$eq: ['$$item.requirementId', 'req10']},  
                {$eq:['$$item.testCaseId', 'tc1']}  
            ]}              
        }}  
    }}  
])
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add example documents to your question?

Comment: Query in spring Mongo will be like this...                                                                          Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("project").is(    
    project)));                                                                             I want full query to statisfy the above condition